# Can you create a type bound that contains a property?

Tags: scala

I want to have a type that I can use like this:

```
class Something[T](...) {

}
```

Where T is a class that has a property of type User.  I guess this would be hard because I would then need to know the name of the property right?

Is that possible?

**Update**

I tried this based on @pamu's answer

http://scastie.org/28397

```
trait GenericMessage {
    def user: User
}

sealed trait UserMessage extends GenericMessage
case class LoginMessage(id: Int, user: User) extends UserMessage

case class User(id: Int)


class UserWorker[UserMessage](name: String) extends Worker[UserMessage](name) {

}

class Worker[T <: GenericMessage](name: String) {
    val tasks = scala.collection.mutable.Queue.empty[T]
}
```

I am getting the error:

```
type arguments [UserMessage] do not conform to class Worker's type parameter bounds [T <: GenericMessage]
[error] class UserWorker[UserMessage](name: String) extends Worker[UserMessage](name) {
```

Comment: This `class UserWorker[UserMessage](...` creates a type parameter named `UserMessage` that shadows the existence of the class with the same name. Simply use `class UserWorker(...` and it compiles.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to know the name of the property

One way is by using the super type which contains the user field and have a constraint the T is the subtype of the trait holding user field

```
case class User(name: String)

trait UserHolder {
  def user: User
}

class Something[T <: UserHolder](value: T) {
  def foo = value.user
}
```

Comment: see my updated answer with an example, getting an error still. thanks!